# Geographic Map Hitcounter

Tags: maps, geoip

I am looking for a stand alone solution similar to clustermaps, etc.

I want to be able to plot visits to my page via geographic location much like the map overview 
statistics on google analytic's.

My application all ready makes use of the MaxMid free geolite  database, but I have been unable to find examples of using the maxmind results to plot co-ordinates on a map.

Php is not my strong point either so Ideally I am looking for example code or a pre made solution.

The stuff I have found so far, like cluster maps etc all require you to link back to their own service, I need a 100% stand alone solution.

Does anybody have some example code using maxmid to plot visits to a graph or something similar?

Thanks in advcance.

Comment: `I need a 100% stand alone solution.`
Are you asking us to create a product for you?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution will depend on the projection[1] of the map you choose. Mercator vs Robinson will require different formulas. Mercator is incredibly common, so a good place to start. Googling around there's a bunch of posts about turning lat & long into x & y for exactly this about the web.

The easiest method is probably some sort of embed, you'll save yourself a lot of math as well as potentially buying a map. Google Maps lets you embed it into your own site, but still add points as required.

[1] Projection - The earth is roundish, maps are flat. The various projections are different attempts to represent this round earth on a flat surface.